# How to stop Blender from simulating smoke when doing some things

Tags: smoke-simulation

So I have a scene with a smoke simulation but when I hide the domain it still calculates the simulation which slows down my computer fro what it would usually be able to do at 30fps plus to 2fps. So how do I stop blender from simulating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bake the simulation to a cache, then blender doesn't need to recalculate the simulation.

In order to bake the cache, you must save your blend file first, otherwise the buttons will be greyed out.

Read more in the [blender manual section on baking smoke](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/smoke/baking.html).

You won't need to hide the domain after you do this, unless of course you don't want to see it.